# How do you get InputColumn names from the Model?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

For example, take `OneHotEncoderModel` but you could take anything from `pyspark.ml.feature` package. When you use `OneHotEncoderEstimator` you have the option to set the `inputCols`. In face you **must** use the `inputCols` and `outputCols` in the constructor.

After you create the corresponding model from the estimator, you cannot retrieve the value for `inputCols` anymore. There is no method like `getInputCols()` to give you that from the given model. If you use `getParam("inputCols")` it will just give you the `Param` description and not its value.

If you look at the serialized model (the metadata file) the value for this param (`inputCols`) is actually written out. See example below:

```
{"class":"org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoderModel","timestamp":1548215172466,"sparkVersion":"2.4.0","uid":"OneHotEncoderEstimator_c5fcbebe4045","paramMap":{"inputCols":["workclass-tmp"],"outputCols":["workclass-encoded"]},"defaultParamMap":{"handleInvalid":"error","dropLast":true}}
```

However I'm looking for a way to get that from the API.

Answer (score 0):

**Correction to my earlier answer:**

the right method is called `getOrDefault`. For instance:

```
model.getOrDefault("inputCols")
```

---

It looks like there is this undocumented way of getting to those values:

```
model._paramMap[model.inputCols]
```

or

```
model._paramMap[model.params["inputCols"]]
```